# What is the best approach handling post queries in CodeIgniter using MVC?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, search, http-post

My view has a search box (but the question is more general than for this scenario) and when you submit your search query, controller checks your input and displays results with pagination.

Now, to enable user to navigate through different pages for this particular search query I have to store the search data (I use flashdata for that) and retrieve page number as an url_segment.

This all works just fine, but the problem is what happens if after user enters the search clicks refresh (or just re-enters search page). Since the date is saved from previous search it displays the same search results, but in this situation I would like to reset my search and show all results. So I was wondering what is the best approach to do that (I think it should be a relatively common question but I can't find any reasonable answer).

In short, how to correctly handle this situation within a controller:

```
1. Show regular page
2. User submits search query, POST contents are saved, results displayed
3. 
   a) If user clicks on pagination link, keep showing results
   b) If user refreshes page, reset search parameters, show full results
```

3-rd step causes me problems, since I have to use a very messy code (essentially, additional parameter to pagination links telling controller is it still part of search query), and I was wondering if there any clean solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: do not store search data in session, do not use post for this, use get instead this will resolve your problem & will allow users to pass the link to friends and it will still work fine, codeigniter's pagination class can use query param to work with get method.

Comment: The clean solution is **you don't want to do that**. If a user refreshes the page, they expect to get the same page, maybe with up-to-date information. If, upon refresh, their search is automatically restarted, that is unexpected and uncommon behavior.